# wget authentication fails against mscep_admin with Extened Protection enabled

Tags: iis, wget, ntlm

I have a group that runs a wget command against mscep_admin on IIS to genrate certificates for Linux devices.  We are enabling extended proction on IIS for mscep_admin.  After doing this the wget command fails to authenticate with 401 unautorized.  How to get I get the wget command to authenticate?

using following command.
wget -O - --no-check-certificate --http-user=xxxx --http-password=xxx https://serverfqdn/certsrv/mscep_admin

I'm not familiar with Linux or wget.  Not sure what to try.

Comment: Based on your description, I'm wondering why you are running an IIS web server on a Linux system? IIS is Microsoft-proprietary web server software that can only run in the Windows operating systems for full support of it and all of its features.  If you would like to run a web server using Linux you should use a native package like apache.

Comment: IIS is running on our Window CA's.

Comment: It sounds like the Extended Protection feature in IIS is preventing your wget command from authenticating. Please check the logs and post details about the error.